# Use Flash TextArea as TinyMCE Editor textarea

Tags: javascript, flash, tinymce, textarea, externalinterface

I have a flash swf file which has TextArea, I want to use that textarea as a TinyMCE textArea.
Please Guide me how to do it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Google for 'flash textarea wysiwyg'

Comment: Is there anyway, i can use maths equation editor inside flash? 
although i have integrated WIRIS Maths equation plugin in My inyMCE editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible due to the fact that a textarea in swf is not a regular html element which tinymce needs for its initialization.